# What does "to the buyer an ego like no other I grant you" mean?

Tags: meaning

I need help understanding a phrase from the movie *Loving Vincent*, a biography of painter Vincent van Gogh.

A group of painters are enjoying drinks and commenting Vincent:

> Henri: We must Be fine, **to the buyer an ego like no other I grant you**.
> But, a weekend painter. Look at him always drawing.

What does "to the buyer an ego like no other I grant you" mean?

Comment: It makes no sense as quoted. _Please give the source of your quotation!_

Comment: I see you did so in an earlier question. The first part makes no sense, but the bolded part probably means "I admit that, to buyers [of paintings?] he had an ego like nobody else".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognise your source as being the movie *Loving Vincent*. Your quotation is missing punctuation, probably because you are getting it from a transcription of the dialogue rather than the actual script.

"**To the buyer!**" is a *toast*. The characters say this as they raise their glasses to drink. It means that the drink is being dedicated to, or is in honour of, the buyer.

"**An ego like no other**" means they think the aforementioned buyer has a large ego. Adding 'like no other' means that the ego is *incomparable* to anyone else's.

"**I grant you**" is an idiomatic way of saying that you accept something is true. It is often said as an aside. In more modern English, some people instead say "*I'll give you that*".